# Retrieving return statement from doInBackground method in AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

This is the snippet of code from one of my activity where I want to implement `AsyncTask` in android. Please tell me if I am going wrong that I can catch/retrive the return statement from `doInBackground` in `onPostExecute` and if this is true, how can I do it?

```
 public class EvaluateTask extends AsyncTask{

    ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(context);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        progress.setMessage("Analysing");
        progress.setIndeterminate(true);
        progress.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
        Evaluate evaluate = new Evaluate(db); //Evaluate class object
        return evaluate.getScore();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
        progress.dismiss();
        Intent i = new Intent(googleAct.this,result.class);
        startActivity(i);

         //ERROR IN FOLLOWING LINE >>>>>>>
         i.putExtra("score",finalScore);

    }
}
```

Please NOTE here that I want to transfer the `score` variable from `Evaluate` class to `result`Activity by the execution of `getScore()` method (which returns `score` variable) in background using AsyncTask.

Comment: What is the type of Class of your store variable. Also what is the error you are getting in put extra. Since you don't have any variable declared as finalscore anywhere, it will give an error. Try utilizing your object o

Comment: you need to read more about `AsyncTask` you are missing some type parameters when extending the class, however, the returned value in doInbackground() should be passed as parameter to onPostexecute() , so you can retrieve the value from parameter `Object o` in `onPostExecute(Object o)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes we can retrieve/catch the return statement from doInBackground() in onPostExecute() if write AsyncTask's class statement properly.

AsyncTask is a generic class that accepts three class type (non-primitive)  parameters. Try below code to understand and get returned value from doInBackground() method.

I am expecting your Evaluate class' getScore() method's return type is int.

```
public class EvaluateTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Integer> {

ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(context);


@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {

    progress.setMessage("Analysing");
    progress.setIndeterminate(true);
    progress.show();
}

@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
    Evaluate evaluate = new Evaluate(db); //Evaluate class object
    return evaluate.getScore();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Integer finalScore) {

    // in this method, parameter "finalScore" is the returned value from doInBackground() method, that you can use now.
    super.onPostExecute(finalScore);
    progress.dismiss();
    Intent i = new Intent(googleAct.this, result.class);
    startActivity(i);

    //I am considering you were expecting below finalScore as the returned value from doInBackground() method.
    //Now there should not be an error. 
    i.putExtra("score", finalScore);
}
}
```

Comment: Hey @Manishoaham , it is still showing error  in this line: `super.onPostExecute(integer); //error in integer word`  @larry . AND yes, `getScore()` returns integer type.

Comment: Actually I used variable "integer" first then edited it to "finalScore" so forgot to edit the same at this line. If you will change it to "finalScore" it would work fine. And also you can up vote the answer if helped to you. :)

Comment: Please review the edit made by me so that others can directly COPY-USE the correct code. I have changed `integer` to `finalScore` in `super.onPostExecute` method as per the correct code requirements.

Answer (score 1):

When you extend `AsyncTask`, you need to specify the type of return data as part of the generic:

```
public class EvaluateTask extends AsyncTask<DbData, Void, String>
```

In this example, I'm using `DbData` to represent what you are using in `doInBackground()` to retrieve/evaluate the data, `db`.  This should be typed appropriately and passed to the task as a parameter.  I'm also assuming the `score` value you wish to return is a `String`.  You can change to whatever *object* type you need (i.e. if it is an `int` then use `Integer`).

Whatever you return from `doInBackground` will be provided as the argument to `onPostExecute`, in my example it will be a `String` with `score` as you returned from `doInBackground`.

Comment: Sorry @Larry but this doesn't seems working correctly!

Comment: You'll have to provide more info on what changes you made and what you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks for the concern but the answer by @Manishoaham above works fine now after editing. I guess that the problem with your answer was the omission of `super.onPostExecute(finalScore)` method.

Comment: You should not have to call through the base class, it is a no-op.